# How to select the records of this month, using Active Record Query Interface in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginner to the ROR programming, I tried to do the selection of schedules with the following code. I got the correct output when i do on my computer, but after deploying in the heroku I am getting error.
Here **dateshedule** is the column of the **Schedule** table.

```
def index
if
 @schedules=Schedule.where("strftime('%m', dateshedule) = ?", Date.today.strftime('%m'))

   else

   @schedules = Schedule.all
  end
```

This is the code in the views/schedules/index.html.erb
[Schedule for this month](/schedules?order=dateshedule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use strftime in the where clause, as it's a ruby function that the underlying database doesn't know about.  This will work better (assuming the spelling of the column and table is correct; it seems inconsistent in your post)

```
@schedules = Schedule.where('dateschedule >= ? AND dateschedule <= ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_month, DateTime.now.end_of_month)
```